# Извлечь значение из объекта foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Есть объект $price_var. Моя задача вытащить у price значение где id = 144. Уже голову сломал. Какое может быть решение?

```
  foreach ($price_var as $unseri => $product) {
                            echo $products_1 = $product->option_value;  // отображается {"version":"1515038110","5ea77b35059fb03b907f457c41d73b42":{"price":{"142":"5000.00","143":"4000.00","144":"3000.00","145":"2000.00","146":"1000.00"},"regular_price":{"142":"5000.00","143":"4000.00","144":"3000.00","145":"2000.00","146":"1000.00"},"sale_price":{"142":"5000.00","143":"4000.00","144":"3000.00","145":"2000.00","146":"1000.00"}},"8228d3dccd7df926e2e381a4db815020":{"price":{"142":"5000.00","143":"4000.00","144":"3000.00","145":"2000.00","146":"1000.00"},"regular_price":{"142":"5000.00","143":"4000.00","144":"3000.00","145":"2000.00","146":"1000.00"},"sale_price":{"142":"5000.00","143":"4000.00","144":"3000.00","145":"2000.00","146":"1000.00"}}}                                                
     }
```

Comment: Вам всегда известно название ключа? "5ea77b35059fb03b907f457c41d73b42", или оно каждый раз разное, и Вам неизвестно?

Comment: каждый раз разное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой вариант работает

```
foreach ($price_var as $unseri => $product) {
    $products_1 = json_decode($product->option_value, true);

    foreach ($products_1 as $a_key => $a_value) {
        // Проверяем, есть ли ключ
        if( array_key_exists('price', $a_value) ){
            $price      = $a_value['price'][144];
            // в $price - хранится искомое значение
        }
    }                                  
}
```